# Hadoop Pig: Show entries using STARTSWITH

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am having issues using the STARTSWITH string function. I want to display all records in System_Period that begins with 20040

```
transactions = LOAD '/home/cloudera/datasets/assignment2/Transactions.csv'
USING PigStorage(',') AS (Branch_Number:int, Contract_Number:int,
Customer_Number:int,Invoice_Date:chararray, Invoice_Number:int,
Product_Number:int, Sales_Amount:double, Employee_Number:int,
Service_Date:chararray, System_Period:int);

sysGroup = GROUP transactions BY System_Period;

sysFilter = FILTER sysGroup BY STARTSWITH(transactions.System_Period, 20040);

DUMP sysFilter;
```

The error I am receiving is

```
Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.STARTSWITH as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`STARTSWITH` is only used to compare a tuple1 with tuple2 to check whether tuple1 contains tuple2. You cannot pass a relation or a bag to that. And one more thing to be noted is it accepts only String(chararray) not an integer. Either FILTER the system_period that begins with 20040 before the GROUP BY and load system_period as chararray and then cast it after the filter as per your need.

```
transactions = LOAD '/home/cloudera/datasets/assignment2/Transactions.csv'
USING PigStorage(',') AS (Branch_Number:int, Contract_Number:int,
Customer_Number:int,Invoice_Date:chararray, Invoice_Number:int,
Product_Number:int, Sales_Amount:double, Employee_Number:int,
Service_Date:chararray, System_Period:chararray);
sysFilter = FILTER transactions BY STARTSWITH(System_Period, '20040');
```

Else after `GROUP BY` `FLATTEN` the result and then filter

```
transactions = LOAD '/home/cloudera/datasets/assignment2/Transactions.csv'
USING PigStorage(',') AS (Branch_Number:int, Contract_Number:int,
Customer_Number:int,Invoice_Date:chararray, Invoice_Number:int,
Product_Number:int, Sales_Amount:double, Employee_Number:int,
Service_Date:chararray, System_Period:chararray);
sysGroup = GROUP transactions BY System_Period;
flatres = FOREACH sysGroup GENERATE group,FLATTEN(transactions);
sysFilter = FILTER flatres BY STARTSWITH(System_Period, '20040');
```